# emacs SGML screwed up by quotes?

Tags: emacs, sgml

I'm troubleshooting a podcast feed.  I'm not sure the best tool for a job like this, but I started by opening the feed in emacs sgml-mode and running sgml-pretty-print hoping to get a better look.

The pretty printing and syntax highlighting do not work properly.  They are thrown off by markup similar to this:

```
<item>
<description>
    <![CDATA[ Some text... "quoted text” ... and so on.]]>
</description>
</item>
```

Notice the opening double quote followed by the closing *back quotes*.  I believe that's valid SGML.  It's inside CDATA.  However at that point emacs pretty printing and syntax highlighting get screwed up.  It can't tell when the quote ends or when the CDATA ends.

Is there some way I can get emacs to handle this document properly?

For the curious, you can see the feed I'm working with is http://audio.commonwealthclub.org/audio/podcast/climateone.xml

Comment: `nxml-mode` understands that file. It also contains a validating parser. I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to *do* with the file, though, so it may not help you much.

Comment: you might also try ```web-mode``` (http://web-mode.org)